# Trying to merge two data frames without using merge() and using union(), match() or %in%

Tags: r

I want to construct two data frames and merge them without using any form of merge(). Instead I need to use set operations union() and match() or %in% operator. The following output must display the content of d1,d2 and the result of merging d1 and d2.

I have figured out how to do this with merge() but I cannot find out how to do it using union() and match() or %in% operator. Or any other way of doing this. Also my output doesn't match what the output should be. Im a beginner thanks for your help.

```
d1.Kids <- c("Jack", "Jill", "Jillian", "John", "James")
d1.States <- c("CA", "MA", "DE", "HI", "PA")

d1 <- data.frame(d1.Kids, d1.States, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d2.Ages <- c(10, 7, 12, 30)
d2.Kids <- c("Jill", "Jillian", "Jack", "Mary")

d2 <- data.frame(d2.Ages, d2.Kids, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Merging two created data frame
merge <- merge(d1, d2, by.x = "d1.Kids", by.y = "d2.Kids", all = TRUE)

print(merge)

Output should be:

  kids    ages states 
1 Jack    12   CA
2 Jill    10   MA
3 Jillian 7    DE
4 John    NA   HI
5 James   NA   PA
6 Mary    30   NA
```

Comment: You forgot to post `d1.Kids`. And, for this, `data.frame` is (much) better than `cbind`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will do what the question asks for.
It seems long but in fact it's the same set of instructions for each of the dataframes to be merged.

```
Kids <- union(d1$d1.Kids, d2$d2.Kids)

States <- rep(NA_character_, length(Kids))
Ages <- rep(NA_real_, length(Kids))

States[match(d1$d1.Kids, Kids)] <- as.character(d1$d1.States)
Ages[match(d2$d2.Kids, Kids)] <- d2$d2.Ages

mrg <- data.frame(Kids, States, Ages)

mrg
#     Kids States Ages
#1    Jack     CA   12
#2    Jill     MA   10
#3 Jillian     DE    7
#4    John     HI   NA
#5   James     PA   NA
#6    Mary   <NA>   30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the ages for jack, Jill and Jillian are mixed up I'm getting Jack(10), Jill(7) and Jillian(12). When it should be Jack(12), Jill(10) and Jillian(7).

Comment: @888 You are right, corrected. See the edit, it now uses `match`, not `%in%`.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
kids <- unique(c(d1$Kids, d2$Kids))
d3 <- data.frame("Kids" = kids, "ages" = NA, "states" = NA)
for (i in seq_along(kids)) {
if (any(d2$Kids == kids[i])) {
d3[which(d3$Kids == kids[i]),]$ages <- d2[which(d2$Kids == kids[i]),]$ages
} 
if (any(d1$Kids == kids[i])) {
d3[which(d1$Kids == kids[i]),]$states <- d1[which(d2$Kids == kids[i]),]$states
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `match` and extractions.

```
nm <- c("kids", "ages", "states")
s1 <- na.omit(match(d1$d1.Kids, d2$d2.Kids))
s2 <- na.omit(match(d2$d2.Kids, d1$d1.Kids))
r1 <- setNames(data.frame(d1[s1, ], d2[s2, 1]), nm)
res <- if (!setequal(d1$d1.Kids, d2$d2.Kids)) {
  r2 <- setNames(data.frame(d1[-s1, ], NA), nm)
  r3 <- setNames(data.frame(d2[-s2, 2], NA, d2[-s2, 1]), nm)
  rbind(r1, r2, r3)
} else {
  r1
}
res
#       kids ages states
# 1     Jack   CA     10
# 2     Jill   MA      7
# 3  Jillian   DE     12
# 4     John   HI     NA
# 5    James   PA     NA
# 11    Mary <NA>     30
```